# Table lookup on a different workbook on fulfilling a criteria - Most efficient way

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 66 columns (representing the Wind turbines) and about 5000 rows of timestamps. I have to check if the value of each cell, in this case velocity, meets a certain criteria, if it does, i extract name of the Wind turbine from the topmost row. Using the name, i need to "lookup" the Wind turbine closest to it from a Matrix in a different sheet and return this.

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Sub ErsetzenNachbar()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim WeaMat As Workbook
    Dim Mat As Range
    Dim Arr2 As Variant
    Dim target As Long
    Dim MOfound As String

    SheetName = "INPUT_WIND"

    'Range in the first Workbook
    Set Rng = wb.Worksheets(SheetName).Range("C2:AG5000")

    'Open the second Workbook
    Set WeaMat = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nikhil.srivatsa\Desktop\WeaMat")

    'Set range for second workbook with the Matrix
    Set Mat = WeaMat.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:AP68")

    'Range into array
    Arr = Rng.Value

    'loop through array
    For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)

       For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)

          If Arr(i, j) = 0.047 Then

         'wind turbine Name from the topmost row
          Arr(LBound(Arr, 1), j) = target

          'look for target in the Matrix and fetch the neighboring turbine here is where i need help!

          End If

       Next j

    Next i


 End Sub
```

For example I look for the cells containing 0,047 (may vary) and get "MO30" the turbine name. Now i lookup MO30 in the Matrix of a second workbook and ask it to fetch MO42 from the Matrix since it is the first closest wind turbine.

[image]
[image]

would using `Collections` or `Dictionary` help in this case? or should I create an array out the Matrix? or use the `Find` function ?

Comment: I would use `Find`, twice. Not sure if you can do this with formulae though. When you look for, eg. 0.047 could it be in any row?

Comment: Are "timestamps" unique? When you bring pictures, it is good to show us the columns letters. The M030 should be find in column A:A of the second workbook? If not, where to look for it?

Comment: @SJR yes, this could be in any cell of the 5000 Rows x 66 Columns

Comment: @yes, the time stamps are unique

Comment: And is MO42 chosen because it's in the cell next to MO30?

Comment: Can "MO30" be found in column A:A or again somewhere on the sheet?

Comment: @SJR yes, correct, MO20 is the next second furthest from MO 30 and so on

Comment: @FaneDuru Unfortunately MO30 can also be found elsewhere in the Matrix, since it is the "neighbor" of another Wind Turbine

Comment: But what if it will be found on the last column?

Comment: In that case how do you know which is the appropriate instance of MO30?

Comment: @FaneDuru The MO in the column next to the MO in Bold are the MOs closest to it. For Example The MO closest to MO30 is MO42, the second closest is MO20 and on on. The Last column will contain an MO furthest from MO30

Comment: @SJR I look up MO30 in the Column where they are marked bold, then i need to fetch the MO in the cell next to it. The MO in Bold is my "lookup" range so to say, using which I need to find the MOs in the same row.

Comment: I've posted an answer but may not quite work. Is the column marked in bold a fixed column?

Comment: @SJr, many thanks, Yes the bold is a fixed column

Comment: Which column is it?

Comment: @SJR, I have Updated the Matrix (second workbook) for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example using two sheets rather than two workbooks, but see if you can adapt it for your set up.

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind1 As Range, s As String, rFind2 As Range

With Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rFind1 = .Find(what:=0.047, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'look for value on sheet1
    If Not rFind1 Is Nothing Then
        s = .Rows(1).Cells(rFind1.Column)  'if found, find corresponding row 1 value
        Set rFind2 = Sheet2.columns(1).Find(what:=s)  'look for this in sheet2
        If Not rFind2 Is Nothing Then MsgBox rFind2.Offset(, 1) 'report contents of cell to the right
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub findTurb()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, rng As Range, strTurb As String
     Const timeSt As Double = 0.047
    Set sh = ActiveSheet           'use here your sheet
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("second") 'use here your sheet
    Set rng = sh.UsedRange.Find(timeSt)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
       strTurb = sh.Cells(1, rng.Column).value
       Set rng = sh2.Range("A1:A" & sh2.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Find(strTurb)
       If Not rng Is Nothing Then
           MsgBox rng.Offset(, 1).value
       End If
   End If
End Sub
```

It can be transformed in a function, receiving time stamp as parameter and returning a string...

Comment: I have Updated the Matrix (second workbook) for clarity

Comment: So, should I understand that the first found turbine name will be found in a specific column of the second workbook? If not, I do not understand what the new matrix does clarify... In fact, did you test the code? MO30 is near MO07...

Comment: I will test it shortly! thanks. The idea is to find the turbines which have 0,047 and then find the turbine closest to it using the matrix.The matrix shows the turbines closest to to a particular turbine. For ex. The 1st closest turbine to MO01 is MO05, the 2nd closest to it is MO02 and so on.

Comment: This is true only if you look for it in the first column. MO01 can also be found in the second column row 5. And its neighbor is MO10... You said it can be anywhere...

Comment: So, the previous found turbine name (in workbook 1) has to be searched only in column A:A of the second workbook?

Comment: @neutronhammer and FaneDuru, please read SJR's answer as it shows the correct usage of`.Find`and how to avoid implicit references to`.ActiveWorkbook` and the use of`CodeNames`!

Comment: True, it has t only be searched in column A.A of the second, thenfind the value of the adjacent cell

Comment: @neutronhammer: I adapted the code to find it in A:A column. Please, test the code.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: Where in my code do you see "references to. `ActiveWorkbook`"? What do you mean by `CodeNames`? Is it something without full reference in my code?

Comment: e.g `Set sh2 = Worksheets("second") `is implicit for`Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("second")`

Comment: The question stated that two sheets of the same workbook will be used. I, of course, used the simplest way to test my solution, but I wrote: `use here your sheet`. And in the code where you sent us ("please read SJR's answer") `Sheet1.Range("A1")` does not refer the active workbook? In such a case, when a single workbook is involved and you use your specific sheet names, it is not of much use to qualify the used worksheets referring the workbook, I would say... If all the function parameters are false or default, the code is preferable to be done as short as possible.

Comment: A sheet exists on a workbook and 2 sheets on different wbs can have same name. Of course usually not an issue until you start switching between workbooks, so resist the beginnings! See [Code Name: Sheet1](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/code-name-sheet1/) for more infos and why to use them!